# what happened to 'generate-all' command in Grails 2.3.8?

Tags: grails

Started a brand new project based on grails 2.3.8 (groovy 2.2.2) and I can't figure out what happened to 'generate-all' command. I have a domain class set up, i was able to create the controller but it beats me to find how views get crated now.
I've gone through the crate-app step and crated 1 domain class. Am I missing a plugin or something? When I look at tutorials they sure refer to the 'geneate-all' command.
Have things changed that much?

Comment: generate-all is still [there](http://grails.org/doc/2.3.8/ref/Command%20Line/generate-all.html)

Comment: do a grails clean and refresh-dependencies then it will work.

Comment: did clean and clean-all, refresh-dependencies now errors out: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: _PluginDependencies_groovy$_createPluginInstallEngine_closure4

Comment: had to restart grails, Joshua, i'll take that as an answer if you like

Comment: Fair enough. Added as an answer.

Comment: @danielad Sorry I didn't really get what you have mentioned.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Typically in 2.3.x when you first create the project "`generate-all`" needs to have a series of Grails `compile`, `clean`, `clean-all` and `refresh-dependency`. Failing that, exit the project and restart. Then it will show as a valid command.

The reason for this is in 2.3.x scaffolding was moved into a plugin and it needs to be compiled first before the command is available.

Comment: Reason: `scaffolding` is its own plugin now in grails-core which has to be compiled first then the command will be available. You can add that to answer to make it complete. :)